# What are the major changes in uploadify API between versions 2 and 3?

Tags: javascript, uploadify

I'm trying to upgrade uploadify 2.1.4 to 3.1, and it seems there are major breaking changes.
So far I only found a few setting keys that were changes (e.g. "uploader" should be changed "swf" and "script" is now "uploader" ... very confusing).

Is there an upgrade guide? More important changes that I'm missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The changes are more than just renaming parameter names. This was one of the more confusing library upgrades I encountered due to all the renames and undocumented API changes (unless there is a migration document somewhere that I missed). In addition to what I described in the question, and minor other changes, I found:

1. In v3, `onUploadComplete` (equivalent to onComplete in v2), doesn't get the response data from the server.
2. In `onUploadSuccess` the meaning of `data` and `response` is now different than in v2. In v2 (onUploadComplete), the method's signature was `function(event, ID, fileObj, response, data)`, and `response` held the actual response bytes, while `data` held metadata like "filecount" and "speed". In v3 (`onuploadsuccess`), `response` is now a boolean (true == success), and `data` is "the data that was returned by the server-side script (anything that was echoed by the file)".

I realized some of the above information just after giving up and reverting to v2.4.1 - it appears the feature I needed was there all along, and I had no need to upgrade.

The feature was subscribing on `onUploadStart` - I just realized that in v2.4.1 it is actually called `onSelectOnce` ... or at least it's a good enough approximation for my purpose.